# Adding -only- root element type info to serialized object in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I know there are options to serialize Type info in Json.Net.

We can add type info to json object as $type property.

But both TypeNameHandling.Objects and TypeNameHandling.Array options increase message size dramatically.

I need to serialize root element type info. I have complex object and I need only main object type info.

How can I achieve it? Could I write new TypeNameHandling or how?

**SAMPLE C# OBJECTS AND DESIRED JSON RESULT**

```
public class MainComplexObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> BList { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public C C { get; set; }
}

public class C
{

}
```

We want to serialize MainComplexObject, desired Json result:

{**"$type":"ns.MyComplexObject, ..."**,"Id":3,BList:[{"Id":85,"Name":"...","C":{...}]}

Only MainComplexObject type is written to Json. There is no type info except that.

**Edit For @dbc 's comment:**

All classed (MyComplexObject,B,C,..)  have Interfaces.

**NOTE**

I want to deserialize it to correct type (MyComplexObject) also.

Comment: do you mind sharing your code? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm) to emit type information only when necessary, then to force type information for the *root object*, use the answer from [Serializing an interface/abstract object using NewtonSoft.JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128923).

Comment: I've edited the question. could you check.

Comment: Is it enough to serialize using `TypeNameHandling.Auto` then do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainComplexObject, typeof(object), settings)` ?  That will emit type information for the root object and not for nested objects *unless needed*.

Comment: Related or identical: [json.net - how to add property $type ONLY on root object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356336).